# Passing data from a BroadcastReceiver to MainActivity works correctly only once

Tags: android, android-activity, android-intent, task, broadcastreceiver

I have a `PushNotificationReceiver (extends BroadcastReceiver)` and `MainActivity`. The receiver sends some data (for example string value "`New value`") to the `MainActivity` via an `Intent`. Then `MainActivity` updates its `TextView` with this value.
This works fine until I change this `TextView` value to some other value (for example reset it to "`UNSPECIFIED`") and move the activity to background and to foreground again. The `MainActivity` is restored and its `TextView` contains "`New value`", however I expected it to be "`UNSPECIFIED`" - **this is the problem**.

What is wrong with my app?

The whole proto project may be downloaded [here](http://www.box.net/shared/si6krushrv).

Here is my MainActivity code

```
private TextView tvValue;
private EditText etNewValue;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    tvValue = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.value);
    etNewValue = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.new_value);

    findViewById(R.id.reset).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {         
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            tvValue.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.not_specified));
        }
    });

    findViewById(R.id.send_notification).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {         
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            sendNotification(etNewValue.getText().toString());
        }
    });

    processDataFromBroadcast(getIntent());        
}

@Override
public void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
    super.onNewIntent(intent);
    processDataFromBroadcast(intent);
}

private void sendNotification(String value){
    NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    String title = "Proto App Notif";

    Notification notification = new Notification(
            android.R.drawable.ic_notification_overlay,
            title,
            System.currentTimeMillis());
    notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;

    Context ctxApp = getApplicationContext();

    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent()
        .setAction(PushNotificationReceiver.ACTION_NOTIFICATION)
        .putExtra("value", value);
    PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
            ctxApp, 
            0, 
            notificationIntent, 
            PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);     

    notification.setLatestEventInfo(
            ctxApp,
            title,
            value,
            contentIntent);

    notification.audioStreamType = AudioManager.STREAM_NOTIFICATION;

    mNotificationManager.notify(1, notification);           
}

private void processDataFromBroadcast(Intent intent) {
    if (!intent.hasExtra("value")){
        return;
    }

    String val = intent.getStringExtra("value");

    tvValue.setText(val); // Updating my activity look
}
```

PushNotificationReceiver

```
private static final String LOG_CAT = "PushNotificationReceiver";
static final String ACTION_NOTIFICATION = "com.mobiwolf.proto.NOTIFICATION_RECEIVER";

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    if (!intent.getAction().equals(ACTION_NOTIFICATION)) {
        return;
    }

    String value = intent.getStringExtra("value");

    Log.d(LOG_CAT, "Received notification message: "+value); // Log always contains the value sent on first time

    Intent i = new Intent();
    i.setClass(context, MainActivity.class);
    i.putExtra("value", value);
    i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

    context.startActivity(i);
}
```

And manifest

```
    <receiver android:name="com.mobiwolf.proto.PushNotificationReceiver">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.mobiwolf.proto.NOTIFICATION_RECEIVER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>    

    <activity android:name=".MainActivity"
              android:label="@string/app_name"
              android:launchMode="singleTask">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Comment: Have you tried using `PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT` instead of `PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT`?

Comment: 2 dave.c - yes, but in fact I see no difference. Actually currently the problem is in activity itself and not in broadcast - when it is restored after background the intent is processed again and textview is set to value from broadcast.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For solving this problem I added global static trigger

```
  /**
  * This class triggers whether pushnotification was handled by MainActivity
  * (Preventing handling this push notification twice when the MainActivity 
  * is moved to background and restored from background
  */
  public final class PushNotifHandledTrigger {
private static boolean handled = true;

public static boolean wasHandled(){
    return handled;
}

public static void set(){
    handled = true;
}

public static void reset(){
    handled = false;
}
  }
```

Then before startActivity I do reset this trigger and set after handling (and of course perform handling only if trigger is not set)

Answer (score 1):

Replace

```
i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
```

by

```
i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP | 
    Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
```

Answer (score 0):

Define a `public static boolean newUpdate;` variable, set it to `true` right before `context.startActivity(i);`. Then, when in your `MainActivity` you check to see the intent has `extra` with it, also verify that `newUpdate` is `true`, and if it is, reset it to `false` and update your `TextView` field. The last function will look like this

```
private void processDataFromBroadcast(Intent intent) {
   if ( !intent.hasExtra("value") || (newUpdate == false) ){ //So only new updates are processed.
      return;
   }
   newUpdate = false; //This action will not be repeated unless another notification arrives
   String val = intent.getStringExtra("value");

   tvValue.setText(val); // Updating my activity look
}
```