# Android Copy & Paste to any text field in any application

Tags: java, android, copy-paste

I am developing an app for commercial use with a background service that is getting transponder numbers (of animals) from an RFID reader via bluetooth.

After processing the received number I would like to send it to the clipboard and **paste it in the focused text field of whatever application is currently in front** which in my case is a browser app.

I already found a [similar question from 2013](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19177231/android-copy-paste-from-clipboard-manager) but with no accepted answer by now. All answers to the question just explained how to use `ClipboardManager` to copy and paste code within the developed application but that has not been meant by the problem as he clarified in a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19177231/android-copy-paste-from-clipboard-manager#comment28373996_19177510).

The simplest scenario that I could imagine is to just **simulate a paste action** on the android device. I would prefer not to need to install a third party app.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Just to add to Kirill's answer and assuming the app has Accessibility permission,

Create a class extending AccessibilityService and override onAccessibilityEvent method.

```
public class SampleAccessibilityService extends AccessibilityService {

    @Override
    public void onAccessibilityEvent(AccessibilityEvent accessibilityEvent) {
        AccessibilityNodeInfo source = accessibilityEvent.getSource();
        if (source != null) {
            AccessibilityNodeInfo rowNode = getRootInActiveWindow();
            if (rowNode != null) {
                for (int i = 0; i < rowNode.getChildCount(); i++) {
                    AccessibilityNodeInfo accessibilityNodeInfo = rowNode.getChild(i);
                    if (accessibilityNodeInfo.isEditable() && accessibilityNodeInfo.isFocused()) {
                        accessibilityNodeInfo.performAction(AccessibilityNodeInfoCompat.ACTION_PASTE);
                        return;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onInterrupt() {

    }
}
```

`accessibilityNodeInfo.performAction(AccessibilityNodeInfoCompat.ACTION_PASTE)` will paste the text that is copied to clipboard.

Also make sure you have right accessibility configuration.

config.xml

```
<accessibility-service xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:accessibilityFlags="flagDefault"
    android:accessibilityEventTypes="typeViewClicked|typeViewFocused"
    android:accessibilityFeedbackType="feedbackGeneric"
    android:notificationTimeout="0"
    android:canRetrieveWindowContent="true"
    android:description="@string/testing" />
```

Here `android:accessibilityEventTypes="typeViewClicked|typeViewFocused"` will filter the events to view click or view focus.

You can also the events based on the packages using `"android:packageNames"` (so that your service won't get called often)

Finally declare the service in manifest,

```
<service android:name=".SampleAccessibilityService"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:permission="android.permission.BIND_ACCESSIBILITY_SERVICE">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.accessibilityservice.AccessibilityService"/>
            </intent-filter>
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.accessibilityservice"
                android:resource="@xml/config" />
</service>
```

Comment: I think that is a very comprehensive answer and so I will Mark it as Answer. It seems to do exactly what we need although I cannot test it at the moment because of other priorities. In addition we found [BluePiano: Bluetooth Keyboard-Wedge for Android from TEC-IT][http://www.tec-it.com/en/software/android/bluepiano/keyboard-wedge/Default.aspx] which will do for now.

Answer (score 6):

If you want your app to interact with an app that isn't yours (the browser) you will have to give this app `accessibility permissions`. those are special kind of permission that allow apps to interact with something that is a bit more senstive.

there are accessibility actions, the one that you are looking for is the 
`AccessibilityNodeInfoCompat.ACTION_PASTE` it allows you to preform a paste into a focused field.

Note that I'd recommend you to replace the browser with a inapp `WebView`, and inject the values with javascript this will be much more robust solution for your automation. you can find more info on how to run JS on a webview here: [How to get return value from javascript in webview of android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3298597/how-to-get-return-value-from-javascript-in-webview-of-android/19077097#19077097)

Comment: Although your answer hits the nail right on the head I opted for Govind's answer because it gives further details.