# Capture Paste event of Clipboard

Tags: android, accessibilityservice, clipboardmanager

Is it possible to capture paste event from **ClipboardManager**? I am able to get copied data using method **onPrimaryClipChanged()** of **ClipboardManager.OnPrimaryClipChangedListener**.

The question is in context to an app which uses Accessibility API.

Comment: have look [Clipboard copy & paste](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19177231/android-copy-paste-from-clipboard-manager)

Comment: I need to capture the moment as soon as it is pasted anywhere i.e. irrespective of application.

Comment: capture the moment means what? you want copy some from clipboard  and paste somewhere ?

Comment: Thanks for your efforts, but this doesn't solve the purpose as i may be dealing with any other app a user can have in his device e.g. google chrome, where i think i can-not get the view as EditText.

Answer (score 1):

Digging further, I found the **Paste** event is captured in **AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_VIEW_TEXT_CHANGED**.

**TYPE_VIEW_TEXT_CHANGED**, is an event type which can be handled while extending **AccessibilityService**.

Posting answer, Just in case it help someone else, as i approximately Spent a day to achieve it.