# Configure html input field so the paste option appears on touch for mobile clients?

Tags: android, html, ios

I have an input field on my website for discount codes. Some mobile users don't understand that they need to long press on the input field for the paste option to appear.

Is it possible to configure the input field so that the paste option appears on touch for mobile clients?

Comment: Please check if this could help you 
 (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19177231/android-copy-paste-from-clipboard-manager)

Comment: No there isn't.  Especially not using html.  You could do it if you were writing an actual app.

Comment: Thanks for your answers