# How to get copied text when I copy some text?

Tags: java, android

I want to get the text wen I select and copy/cut any text on android.

Simply when we select any text and copy it, it gets saved. Now I want to get that text from an android app. when I oppen that app I want to get that copied text.

Please help me.

Thanks.

Comment: Use `ClipboardManager`.

Comment: please , check this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19177231/android-copy-paste-from-clipboard-manager

Comment: Thanks a lot. The answer was very helpful.❤